# doctrine-behaviors translatable index identifier too long on mariadb

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, mariadb

I'm using Symfony 4 with flex and tried to make some translation tables with the [KNP Labs - Doctrine Behaviors](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors) but the index name auto generated by Symfony is too long for MariaDb. At least I understand this from the error:

> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 125:
>
> An exception occurred while executing

```
CREATE TABLE app_menu_trans (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
    translatable_id INT DEFAULT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR(255 ) NOT NULL, 
    locale VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    INDEX IDX_B79696A62C2AC5D3 (trans latable_id), 
    UNIQUE INDEX app_menu_trans_unique_translation (translatable_id, locale), 
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_
```

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified
>   key was t   oo long; max key length is 767 bytes
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 109:
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified
>   key was t   oo long; max key length is 767 bytes
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 107:
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified
>   key was t   oo long; max key length is 767 bytes

Something's fishy here, because MariaDb specs say that :

> Databases, tables, columns, indexes, constraints, stored routines,
>   triggers, events, views, tablespaces, servers and log file groups have
>   an maximum length of 64 characters.

I'm not advanced enough to understand what is wrong and how to get around it.
My Translation Table class below:

```
namespace App\Entity;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_menu_trans")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class MenuTranslation
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translation;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return MenuTranslationTranslation
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't the time now but the short explanation is that using `utf8mb4` the max length is limited to 191 chars. Searching a bit you will find tons of posts about this and if I remember well this should be already fixed in the last releases of mysql.

Comment: @RickJames Good! I don't understand why you mentioned me but with your reputation you should know you should avoid only-link answers adding the main details directly in your answer right? :-) (_links are good only for reference and could change over time_).

Comment: @gp_sflover - Yeah, I get chastised for link-only answers.  But my 30+ blogs are designed primarily for providing answers like this, _so I can move on to the next question faster_.  Oracle is doing a good job of obviating my blogs.  This particular one is "eliminated" by 5.7, but I keep it around for those who have not upgraded.  (I keep them all around anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 workarounds for the 767 error: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes

If you are hitting the limit because of trying to use CHARACTER SET utf8mb4. Then do one of the following (each has a drawback) to avoid the error:

```
⚈  Upgrade to 5.7.7 for 3072 byte limit -- your cloud may not provide this; 
⚈  Change 255 to 191 on the VARCHAR -- you lose any values longer than 191 characters; 
⚈  ALTER .. CONVERT TO utf8 -- you lose Emoji and some of Chinese; 
⚈  Use a "prefix" index -- you lose some of the performance benefits.
```

Or... Stay with 5.6/5.5/10.1 but perform 4 steps to raise the limit to 3072 bytes:

```
   SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format=Barracuda;
   SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table=1;
   SET GLOBAL innodb_large_prefix=1;
   logout & login (to get the global values);
   ALTER TABLE tbl ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;  -- (or COMPRESSED)
```

Comment: Or just change `locale` length to 191, if you can.

Comment: @ŁukaszJakubek - That's the second bullet item.